# Simulate MousePress to enter MouseDragged

Tags: java, jframe, mouseevent, mouselistener

**I am trying to achieve:**

1. User performs a mouse-press on parent JFrame
2. Child JFrame becomes visible at mouse location
3. While mouse-button remains pressed, the user can drag the child JFrame across the screen by moving the mouse

**The problem:**

I can mimic a mouse-press but it does not 'grab' the child JFrame--hence the child JFrame is not being dragged unless the user manually clicks the child JFrame again. I want the process to be smooth without any interruptions: i.e. steps 1-3 (above) should all execute with a single mouse-press.

**Failed attempts:**
 
1. I have tried using Robot's mousePressed() to simulate an additional mouse-press on the child. This works, however, it's not clean and can be quite buggy--especially if the PC/device is slow or the user moves the mouse too quickly. This is not a good solution.
2. Using the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(new MouseEvent());` results in the exact same issue as depicted by the current code.
3. When adding a KeyListener (for testing) to both the child and the parent, when the mouse-press is made, the child window is focused and responds to the implemented KeyListener--the parent's KeyListener is not activated..

**The Code:**

```
    final JFrame parent = new JFrame(), child = new JFrame();
    parent.setSize(256, 256);
    child.setSize(128,128);
    parent.setVisible(true);

    parent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            child.setVisible(true);
            child.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen()-48, e.getYOnScreen()-48);
            int id = MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED;
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int x = 48;
            int y = 48;
            int button = MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK;
            child.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(child, id, time, button, x, y, 1, false));
        }
    });

    child.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            child.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen()-48, e.getYOnScreen()-48);
        }
    });

    child.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Pressed!");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the child JFrame has the focus, the MousePress remains active on the parent. To resolve the issue in a stable manner, the parent should 'forward' its MouseDragged event to the child as shown below:

```
    parent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            child.setVisible(true);
            child.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen()-48, e.getYOnScreen()-48);
        }
    });

    parent.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            child.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(child, e.getID(), e.getWhen(), e.getButton(), e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger()));
        }
    });

    child.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            child.setLocation(parent.getX()+e.getX()-48, parent.getY()+e.getY()-48);
        }
    });
```

Even this is not fully 'clean' because the code is relying on the parent's frame visibility. However, it is a stable solution (unlike Robot).